# Find a closed form formula for $P(X\in k\mathbb{Z})$, for $X\in\text{Po}(\gamma)$.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, roots-of-unity

> For $k\ge3$, using the fact that the probability generating function for $X$ extends to a $k$-th complex root of unity, find a closed form formula for $P(X\in k\mathbb{Z})$, for $X\in\text{Po}(\gamma)$.

Using the fact that the probability generating function for $X$, $E[s^X]=e^{\gamma(s-1)}$, extends to a $k$-th complex root of unity, we get that
\begin{align*}
e^{\gamma(\eta-1)}&=\sum_{n\ge0}\eta^n\cdot\frac{\gamma^n}{n!}e^{-\gamma}\\
&=\sum_{m\in k\mathbb{Z}}\frac{\gamma^m}{m!}e^{-\gamma}+\sum_{m\notin k\mathbb{Z}}\eta^m\cdot\frac{\gamma^m}{m!}e^{-\gamma}
\end{align*}
Which implies that
\begin{align*}
P(X\in k\mathbb{Z})&=\sum_{m\in k\mathbb{Z}}\frac{\gamma^m}{m!}e^{-\gamma}\\
&=e^{\gamma(\eta-1)}-\sum_{m\notin k\mathbb{Z}}\eta^m\cdot\frac{\gamma^m}{m!}e^{-\gamma}
\end{align*}
Now from here I do not know how to write this sum in a closed form, any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.